# Is that possible to make a Keycloak listener based on Keycloak SPI to copy the configuration from realm to new created realm?

Tags: plugins, keycloak

We have a use case when the user create a new realm (E.g.: "realmNew")in Keycloak, some configs and resource in an existed realm (e.g.: all roles  in "realmOld") needs to be copied into the new created realm.

I did some research and found Keycloak provides SPI to implement the plugin which listen the specific event and do the operation.
In my case, the event will be realm creation. When I try to implement the interface `EventListenerProvider` in plugin, I found the method in this interface:

```
void onEvent(AdminEvent event, boolean includeRepresentation);
```

The input is the `AdminEvent` class. So it means the listener has no way to access any internal resources of keycloak (E.g.: realm, roles, users ...)
In this case, it seems that the listener plugin based on Keycloak SPI won't work for my design. I should find another approach.

Anyone has idea whether my understanding is correct ?  Or any suggestions ?

Comment: I'm curious why Users are creating Realms? This does not seem User-like activity.

Comment: This is the functionality that keycloak provides. User may need to manage the user profiles in different realm for better management. Then they can create realm.

Answer (score 0):

Following someone's suggestion then I did some investigation. I can see every Provider class has an corresponding ProviderFactory class/interface, in the method:

```
public EventListenerProvider create(KeycloakSession session)
```

An instance of the KeycloakSession is being available at runtime. So the session object can be used to get a lot of inner resource, which makes the operation I plan to do be feasible.